# Scraping Complex Forms using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Below is a snippet of my Python code along with HTML from a page I'm trying to scrape.

The HTML is a complex form I'm having trouble scraping. I'm using BeautifulSoup4 and Python Requests however when I post to the page theform isn't properly receiving the correct inputs. I'm guessing it has something to do with all these hidden inputs above the actual select I'm trying to submit.

If I inspect the form-data being submitted while using Chrome, here's what I see.

[Chrome Developer Console View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwIZz.png)

When using the page through the browser the only field that has to be selected is the *select name="sel_subj* as seen below. However when posting back to the page this fails

```html
new_url = 'https://wl11gp.neu.edu/udcprod8/NEUCLSS.p_class_search'

requests.post(new_url, data={'STU_TERM_IN':201730,
                            'p_msg_code': UNSECURED',
                            'sel_subj': 'ACCT'})
```

To view a live version of the page I'm trying to scrape visit this link, select "Spring 2017 Semester" and click submit: https://wl11gp.neu.edu/udcprod8/NEUCLSS.p_disp_dyn_sched

Comment: where is you code ?

Comment: just added it, sorry about that!

Comment: first you need to make `get` request ( given url) and then u need to make `post` request which you need to send 2 post paramters `p_msg_code=UNSECURED&STU_TERM_IN=201754`

Comment: The form I'm trying to submit is actually the one on the next page with the sel_subj attribute. I tried submitting a payload with `p_msg_code`, `STU_TERM_IN`, and `sel_subj` but I just get a 404 error.

Comment: I added my post code above.